# Blind SQL Injection on a HP printer?

Tags: vulnerability, vulnerability-scanners

The vulnerability test from Nexpose scanned the HP printers and last scan shows

> "Blind SQL Injection / Remedation plan: Ensure that the Web
> application validates and encodes user input before using it in a SQL
> query.", CVSS 9.

Can someone explain how a printer can have this vulnerability? Is it a false positive? Firmware update was done, but the scan still shows it.

Comment: We can't tell you if it is a false positive. Any web page with a SQL backend can have this vulnerability. It's feasible that a printer that has a web page could have this vulnerability.

Comment: If the printer is running a SQL Server then it of course might be vulnerable.